# is there any java plugin to generate DDL for Oracle,MySQL,PostGreSQL?

Tags: java, database, comparison

I am comparing two database in java using jdbc meta data.
Steps followed in comparison is :
Fist check for common schema->For all common schema found common table->for all common table find common column(considering column datatype,size,scale,isNull,orderInDB) ,check for primary key,foreign key.

Now If I note any difference in any property then I want to generate appropriate DDL so that I can execute on a database and make the two database equal.

Is there any java plugin which can help me out? Let me know any strategy which will be helpful in accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a marvelous [Schemacrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/index.html) API kit, which does what you really need - parse DB schema and, if needed, create a diff-able output. I suggest You go with that, since it's very easy to use and there is a bunch of good snippets on the website.

Comment: ,I was going through schema crawler,There nice api is provided to crawl through schema,but I didint found any api using which I can get a diff sql query to be executed,I mean if suppose I compared two database then is there any api which can give me a list of query which can be executed on a particular database to make both of them equal? Also plz tell me how can I use schema crawler to generated ER diagram using java api?

Comment: Creating DB diagram with SchemaCrawler is easy, take a look at [this FAQ entry](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/faq.html#diagrams). There is also a Maven task which can generate a nice HTML report.

Comment: Comparing the databases is a little trickier. I do this by comparing two DB schemas and generate appropriate entries for [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/overview). After that the XML file is stored in GIT. It's not perfect, it required me to create a specific M2 plugin to create the files, but it was fairly easy since [Schemacrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) is using Velocity to handle the output. BTW, the plugin is proprietary with rights being held by a customer of mine and I tried to Open Source it before... still I can not make him change his mind about it.

Comment: If you're willing to put your checkbook in work, there are commercial tools that do exactly what I did for my customer:

Comment: :( dont have money..but have brain..ur idea of liquibase is nice..surely will give a try

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation before, While my solution is to generate the DDL by myself. since you have all the metas for that table, you can easily generate it, isn't it? The key point is composite  index. Besides, you also need to know the different types among these databases.

Comment: Can you paste that segment of code? Would really help me out..thanks

Comment: Sorry, it's company property, so I can't just paste here. but actually the method is just use a StringBuilder , then append and append ....

Answer (score 0):

For oracle you can use scheme2ddl from http://code.google.com/p/oracle-ddl2svn/ toolset